# insert elements into 2 D array

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

say I have a 2 dimensionsal array like

```
a={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

and a vector like

```
v={10,11,12}
```

I want the result to be

```
{{{10,1},{10,2},{10,3}},{{11,4},{11,5},{11,6}},{{12,7},{12,8},{12,9}}}
```

What command should I use?
Thank you for suggestions.
regards, hal.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better solution, but this should work.

**Example:**

```
a={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
v={10,11,12}

Thread[List[v[[#]], a[[#]]]] & /@ Range @ Length @ v
```

**Alternative:**

```
MapThread[Thread[{##}] &, {v, a}]
```

**Output:**

```
(*{{{10, 1}, {10, 2}, {10, 3}}, {{11, 4}, {11, 5}, {11, 6}}, {{12, 
   7}, {12, 8}, {12, 9}}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick way to get there,

```
Thread /@ Transpose@{v, a}

(* {{{10, 1}, {10, 2}, {10, 3}}, {{11, 4}, {11, 5}, {11, 
   6}}, {{12, 7}, {12, 8}, {12, 9}}} *)
```

The point here is that `Transpose@{v, a}` gives `{{10, {1, 2, 3}}, {11, {4, 5, 6}}, {12, {7, 8, 9}}}`, and you can use `Thread` on the individual elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired result in many ways with Mathematica. Just some variants in addition:

```
MapThread[Thread[{##}] &, {v, a}]
Inner[Thread[{#1, #2}] &, v, a, List]
g[x_, y_] := Prepend[{#}, y] & /@ x;
h[x_, y_] := {y, #} & /@ x;
t = Thread[{a, v}];
g @@@ t
h @@@ t
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MapThread[Map[t \[Function] {#1, t}, #2] &, {v, a}]
```

Comment: thank you, also for pointing out the relation to similar post about MapThread.